# QuantStrat sigFormula

Tags: r, quantstrat

I am having problem with regards to running `sigFormula`. I am getting the error:

```
Error in is.character(x) : 'x' is missing
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = seq(ncol(tmp_val))) : 
  attempt to set colnames on object with less than two dimensions
```

It seems to occur ether in `applySignal` or `applyStrategy`. What does it mean? Is there a bug inside `sigFormula`?

My code:

```
library(quantstrat)

#set currency
currency('USD')

#Get Data
initDate="2000-01-01" 
endDate="2014-05-31"  
symbols = c("SPY")
for(symbol in symbols){
    stock(symbol, currency="USD",multiplier=1) #financial instrument and 
    getSymbols(symbols,from=initDate,to=endDate)
    assign(symbol, adjustOHLC(get(symbol),use.Adjusted=TRUE))
}

#Initialize Portfolio,Strategy,Orders,and Account
initEq=1000000
portfolio.st='db'
account.st='db'
initPortf(portfolio.st,symbols=symbols, initDate=initDate)
initAcct(account.st,portfolios=portfolio.st, initDate=initDate)
initOrders(portfolio=portfolio.st,initDate=initDate)
lookback = 50

strat<- strategy(portfolio.st)

ROC2 <- function(x, n = 50, ...)
{
    roc <- ROC(Cl(x), n)
    colnames(roc) <- NULL
    roc
}

TSI <- function(x, nShort = 10, nLong = 100)
{
    atr <- ATR(HLC(x), nShort)$atr
    absd <- abs(diff(Cl(x), nShort))
    ratio <- absd / atr
    tsi <- runMean(runMean(ratio, nShort), nLong)

    # SMA gives the same result as runMean
    #tsi <- SMA(SMA(ratio, nShort), nLong)
    # not needed, as runMean removes colname
    #colnames(tsi) <- NULL
    tsi
}

strat <- add.indicator(strategy=strat, name="SMA", arguments=list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=50), label="SMA50")
strat <- add.indicator(strategy=strat, name="ROC2", arguments=list(x = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=150), label="ROC150")
strat <- add.indicator(strategy=strat, name="TSI", arguments=list(x = quote((mktdata)), nShort=10, nLong=100), label="TSI")
strat <- add.indicator(strategy=strat, name="RSI", arguments=list(price = quote(Cl(mktdata)), n=2), label="RSI")

# for debugging purposes
#strat.ind <- applyIndicators(strategy=strat, mktdata=get(symbol))
#tail(strat.ind)


# Cl > SMA(50)
strat <- add.signal(strat, name="sigComparison", arguments=list(columns=c("Close", "SMA50"), relationship="gt"), label="Cl.gt.SMA50")
# ROC(150) > 0
strat <- add.signal(strat, name="sigThreshold", arguments=list(column="ROC150", threshold=0), label="ROC150.gt.zero")
# LongCond: either Cl>SMA or ROC(150) == TRUE
strat <- add.signal(strat, name="sigFormula", arguments=list(columns=c("Cl.gt.SMA50", "ROC150.gt.zero"), formula="(Cl.gt.SMA50 == 1) | (ROC150.gt.zero == 1)", cross=FALSE), label="LongCond")
# Setup1 = LC and (TSI/RSI or TSI/RSI)
strat <- add.signal(strat, name="sigFormula",  arguments=list(columns=c("LongCond", "TSI", "RSI"), formula="(LongCond == 1) & (((TSI > 1.65) & (RSI < 18)) | ((TSI < 1.65) & (RSI < 8)))", cross=FALSE), label="Setup1")
# Setup2 = LC and (TSI/RSI or TSI/RSI)
strat <- add.signal(strat, name="sigFormula", arguments=list(columns=c("LongCond", "TSI", "RSI"), formula="(LongCond != 1) & (((TSI > 1.65) & (RSI < 13)) | ((TSI < 1.65) & (RSI < 2)))", cross=FALSE), label="Setup2")
# Entry = Setup1 or Setup2 == TRUE
strat <- add.signal(strat, name="sigFormula", arguments=list(columns=c("Setup1", "Setup2"), formula="((Setup1 == 1) | (Setup2 == 1))", cross=FALSE), label="EntryCond")
# Exit = TSI/RSI or TSI/RSI
strat <- add.signal(strat, name="sigFormula", arguments=list(columns=c("TSI", "RSI"), formula="(((TSI > 1.65) & (RSI > 61)) | ((TSI < 1.65) & (RSI > 39)))", cross=FALSE), label="ExitCond")

# For debugging purposes. For some reason this does not work, even though
# applyStrategy creates the columns properly?
#strat.sig <- applySignals(strategy=strat, mktdata=SPY, indicators=strat.ind)
#tail(strat.sig)

# entry rule
strat <- add.rule(strat, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="EntryCond", sigval=TRUE, orderqty=1000, ordertype="market", orderside="long", pricemethod="market"), type="enter")
# exit rule
# this generates a large number of orders into order book, which
# subsequently are rejected
strat <- add.rule(strat, name="ruleSignal", arguments=list(sigcol="ExitCond", sigval=TRUE, orderqty="all", ordertype="market", orderside="long", pricemethod="market", orderset="exit1"), type="exit")


out <- try(applyStrategy(strategy=strat, portfolios='db'))
updatePortf(Portfolio=strat.name, Dates=paste("::", as.Date(Sys.time()), sep=""))
chart.Posn(Portfolio = strat.name, Symbol=symbol)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `mktdata` object.  It doesn't have a `TSI` column, so your attempt to reference that column in `sigFormula` fails and the lexical scope search finds your `TSI` function instead.

```
R> colnames(mktdata)
 [1] "SPY.Open"     "SPY.High"     "SPY.Low"      "SPY.Close"    "SPY.Volume"  
 [6] "SPY.Adjusted" "SMA.SMA50"    "X1.ROC150"    "X1.TSI"       "RSI"
```

The solution is to set the column names on the output of the `TSI` function in the function's definition:

```
TSI <- function(x, nShort = 10, nLong = 100)
{
    atr <- ATR(HLC(x), nShort)$atr
    absd <- abs(diff(Cl(x), nShort))
    ratio <- absd / atr
    tsi <- runMean(runMean(ratio, nShort), nLong)
    colnames(tsi) <- "TSI"
    tsi
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error, when I replace TSI function with the one you suggested which changes the `colnames`. I searched online about this problem: https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?func=detail&atid=1271&aid=2680&group_id=316

Comment: this link suggested an alternative `sigFormula` function which solves my other system's codes same problem but it doesn't solve this one that I am having.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. Your code runs for me when I use the latest quantstrat and TTR from R-Forge and make sure that the formula variables match the `mktdata` colnames.

Comment: I am using blotter version= `0.8.19`, quanstrat = '0.8.2', financial instrument = '1.1.9' with R version = `2.15.3`.

Comment: when you say formula variables should match the mktdata object, I find that whenever I run `applyIndicator`, the colnames of `mktdata` always concatenates extra symbols, in your above example `x1`; does that affect the problem?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the problem. I'm not particularly fond of that behavior, but a better solution would be complicated and take much time to implement.  Also, you should upgrade your R installation if you can. Yours is 1.5 years old.

Comment: i mean that behavior seems to works and don't seem to cause problems in my implementations without the use of `sigFormula`. What is the complicated solution that you are talking about? I really want to get this working as its the only road block that I am having...thanks anyway.

Comment: If you don't use `sigFormula`, we use partial matching to lookup the column names. R's `formula` class does not use partial matching, so you have to make sure your variables match the column names exactly. The more complicated solution is to design, create, and test some new way to ensure the column names of the `mktdata` object have unique and friendly names.

Answer (score 0):

define you own RSI

```
RSII <- function(price, n)
{
  rsi <- RSI(price=price, n=n)
  colnames(rsi) <- "RSII"
  rsi
}
```

replace all RSI with RSII in rest of your codes